# Uniform continuity of $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ on $(-2,\infty)$

Tags: functions, uniform-continuity

Is the function $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ uniformly continuous on $(-2,\infty)$?   I know how to prove this for the case when the domain is closed or is, say,  $[-1, \infty)$,  but I am not sure how to estimate the fraction from above when working with this domain.

Comment: If it were uniformly continuous, what could you say about $f$ on the interval $(-2,0]$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, then $f$ is bounded on that interval?

Comment: So when $x$ goes to -2, $f$ goes to $\infty$, hence, $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, uniformly continuous functions must be bounded on bounded intervals, and $f$ is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider taking two sequences: ${x_n}= -2 + \frac {1}{n}$ and ${y_n}= -2 + \frac {1}{2n}$, from there argue by contradiction.